# Chrome v.66 Autoplay on Mobile Browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, chromium, autoplay

I am trying to create a feature wherein an image with play icon is shown and when the user clicks on the icon, we load the video in an iframe in a popup. According to this  [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) , iframe should be allowed to autoplay if user interacted with the website using allow='autoplay' attribute. But this doesnt seem to work in our case on **Chrome mobile browser v.66**. Since we are loading the video only after the user clicks on play, it should be a legitimate case of user interaction I suppose.Is there something that I am missing out ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that *Chrome for Mobile* still requires that you handle this from the user-gesture event itself <sub>(just like Safari btw)</sub>.

The time your iframe loads, your user-gesture approval will have expired, and you wont be able to auto-play nor programmatically play your `<video>` with sound.

One way around though, **if your iframe doc is on the same domain**, is to load an other `<video>` element from the main document, inside the user-gesture event, to mark it as user approved (by calling *MediaElement.play()*), and once your iframe has loaded to replace your iframe's element with this user-approved one in the iframe's doc.

```js
btn.onclick = e => { // we must have an user-gesture event
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); // your iframe
  const frameContent = `<html>
    <body>
      <video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm"></video>
    </body>
  </html>`;
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([frameContent], {type: "text/html"}));
  // Our user-approved <video>
  const vid = document.createElement('video');
  vid.play().catch(e => null); // mark it as 'user-approved'
  vid.autoplay = true;

  iframe.onload = e => { // once our iframe have loaded
   // swap both elements
   const i_vid =  iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('video');
   i_vid.replaceWith(vid);
   vid.src = i_vid.currentSrc;
  };
  iframe.src = url;
  document.body.append(iframe);
};
```

StackSnippet's <sup><sub>over-</sub></sup> protected iframes won't allow us to manipulate this inner frame, so here is a [live jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/223uk2qz/).